# RPC will not connect to daemon

Tags: daemon, rpc, monero-wallet-rpc

I attempted to run the Monero RPC, but I am not able to connect to the daemon on either my VPS, which is running a synchronized daemon, or on my Windows PC.  This is what happened

I started by running it on my ARM v7 VPS, which already has the daemon downloaded
This is the command that I used to run the daemon

> ./monerod

After this synced, I ran

> ./monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port=18081 --wallet-file Webminer

RPC ends up displaying this

[image: Monero 1]

Then I tried to connect to a remote node, which failed so I did it on my one pc

> Monero 'Helium Hydra' (v0.11.1.0-release)
>   Logging to E:\Programs\Monero\monero-gui-win-x64-v0.11.1.0\monero-gui-v0.11.1.0\monero-wallet-rpc.log
>   2018-03-07 21:04:43.613 9148    WARN    wallet.rpc      src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server.cpp:1853   Loading wallet...
>   Wallet password: ********
>   2018-03-07 21:04:51.544 9148    WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:2505     Loaded wallet keys file, with public address: 488DS1c1SBfLr5L1JLCL7hKUTPCEiSVxuT7SkjkCzc7K8uRcjbi15S5Y2CLGcaszHQb31xcCQqShQDdHSymijyBkMXvPKMQ
>   2018-03-07 21:04:52.761 9148    ERROR   net.http        src/wallet/node_rpc_proxy.cpp:82        Failed to connect to daemon
>   2018-03-07 21:04:52.761 9148    ERROR   wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1190     result->empty(). THROW EXCEPTION: tools::error::no_connection_to_daemon
>   2018-03-07 21:04:52.762 9148    WARN    net.http        src/wallet/wallet_errors.h:707  C:/msys64/DISTRIBUTION-BUILD/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1190:N5tools5error23no_connection_to_daemonE: no connection to daemon, request = getversion
>   2018-03-07 21:04:52.762 9148    ERROR   wallet.rpc      src/wallet/wallet_rpc_server.cpp:1887   Wallet initialization failed: no connection to daemon

Thank you!!